# How to make the ChartView X-axis move horizontally and smoothly with qml

Tags: c++, qml

How to make the coordinate axis X move smoother during dynamic movement of qmlChartview? Currently, I am only changing the X axis and comparing it to a single board. Here is my code

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtCharts 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3


Item {
  objectName: "root"

  visible: true
  property var seriesList: [
  //{id: "series1", name: "BX", color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series2", name: "BY",visible:true, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series3", name: "B0",visible:true, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series4", name: "GX",visible:false, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series5", name: "GY",visible:false, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series6", name: "G0",visible:false, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series7", name: "RX",visible:false, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series8", name: "RY",visible:false, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())},
  {id: "series9", name: "R0",visible:false, color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())}]
  property var currentStarttime: new Date(Date.now())     // 开始时间
  property var currentEndtime:new Date(Date.now()+5000)   // 结束时间
  property int currentX: 0
  property int currentY: 0



  //调用过来的信号
  signal cSignal(int i, var time,int Ydata);

    //widget 定时器
    onCSignal: {
     var ser=charvi.series(i);
     ser.append(time,Ydata)
      console.log(time,Ydata)
    currentStarttime=new Date(Date.now()-9000);
    currentEndtime=new Date(Date.now()+2500)
    }


  ChartView {
    theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
    anchors.fill: parent
    id: charvi
    legend.visible: false
    antialiasing: true //反锯齿
    objectName :"chartview"

    //X轴
    DateTimeAxis {
      gridVisible: true
      id: xAxis
      min: currentStarttime
      max: currentEndtime
      //format: "hh:mm:ss< br>yyyy-MM-dd "
      format: "hh:mm:ss"
      tickCount: 5
    }
    //leftY轴
    ValueAxis {
      id: yAxis
      min: -40
      max: 40
      tickCount: 5
      minorTickCount: 5
    }
    //RightY轴
    ValueAxis {
      id: rightyAxis
      min:-40
      max:40
      tickCount: 5
      minorTickCount: 5
    }


    //鼠标事件相关
    MouseArea{

      hoverEnabled:false
      //acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.MiddleButton
      id:mouseArea
      anchors.fill: parent

      //中键
      onWheel: {
        if(wheel.angleDelta.y>0){
            charvi.zoom(1.1)
            charvi.scrollRight(40)
        }
        else{
            charvi.zoom(0.9)
        }
      }

      //点击位置
      onPressed:{
        mouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ClosedHandCursor
                    currentX = mouse.x
                    currentY = mouse.y}


      //释放位置
      onReleased:{
          mouseArea.cursorShape = Qt.ArrowCursorArrowCursor //拖动的图标
      }


      onPositionChanged:{

        var moveX = mouse.x-currentX
        var moveY = mouse.y-currentY
        currentX = mouse.x
        currentY = mouse.y
        charvi.scrollLeft(moveX)
        charvi.scrollUp(moveY)
      }


    }
    //-------------------------自定义图例
    MyLegend {
      id: myLegend
      height: 30
      width: 120
      labelColor: "gray"

      anchors.top: parent.top
      anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
      anchors.topMargin: 4
      anchors.horizontalCenterOffset: -150
    }

    LineSeries {
      id: series1
      name: "BX"
      axisAngular: xAxis
      axisYRight: rightyAxis
      color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random())
      visible: true
      //使用GL渲染
      useOpenGL: true
    }

    function recvdatashow(inedex,x,y){
      var ser=charvi.series(inedex);
      var t=Math.random()*4;
      ser.append(x,y)
      ser.append(new Date(Date.now()+5000),y)

    }

    //------------------------初始化
    Component.onCompleted: {
      createLineSeries()
      timer.start()
    }
   }

    Connections {target: myLegend;onSelected: {series.visible = !series.visible } }
    //Conections  {}

    //-------------------------Api
    function createLineSeries() {   //创建Series的数据线.
      myLegend.addSeries(series1, series1.name, series1.color,series1.visible)
      for (var i = 0; i < seriesList.length; i++) {
        var series=0
        series = charvi.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeLine, seriesList[i].name, xAxis, yAxis)
        series.useOpenGL=true;
        series.id=seriesList[i].id
        series.name=seriesList[i].name
        series.color = seriesList[i].color
        series.visible=seriesList[i].visible
        //添加线数据到图例中，进行对series的控制隐藏
        myLegend.addSeries(series, series.name, series.color,series.visible)
        charvi.seriesAdded(series)
      } }


   //-------------------------定时器实验数据
    Timer{
        id:timer
        interval :100
        repeat :true
        onTriggered: {

        //实验数据遍历显示所有的Line
        for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
          var ser=charvi.series(i);
        //  console.log(ser)
          ser.clear()
          var t=Math.random()*4;
          ser.append(new Date,t)
          ser.append(new Date(Date.now()+5000),t)
        }

        //更新坐标
        currentStarttime=new Date();
        currentEndtime=new Date(Date.now()+5000)
        xAxis.rangeChanged(currentStarttime,currentEndtime)}

      }
}
```

I currently use a timer to update my X-axis min and max, but this method is not as effective as the third-party library QCusolitChart compared to single boards